# How to find new positions for divided circle to create 80px gaps

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I divided the circle below using the following steps:

1. made a perfect circle
2. created two lines at 75 and 105° rotation
3. used the pathfinder divide tool to separate the circle.

[image]

I want to know (how to calculate) the positions I would have to move each part of the circle to create an 80px gap. I would like to move each of them by an equal distance to create the 80px gap, as in the image. How can I find the new positions?

Comment: Each of the intersections is at an angle of 15° from vertical. At 45°, you'd move it as far down as sideways, so 45° = 100% and 15° is then 33.3%. Shouldn't this just be moving the side bits 80px to the side and then 1/3 of 80px (26.6px) downwards? (Disclaimer: IANAM!) **Edit:** Actually, easier way. Just rotate the whole thing -15°, move side bit 80px to the side, rotate whole thing 30°, move other side 80px to the side, and rotate whole thing -15° to get back to starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Offset Path feature (*Object → Path → Offset Path...*) on both line segments.

If those segments are already part of a larger path then just select the segments you need with the Direct Selection tool, then copy paste them... Run the Offset Path on both...

[image]

Then delete the parts you don't need...

[image]